# floating point 0.2 + 0.1 rounding error

Tags: javascript, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I came across this rounding issue:

When I do this:

```
 .2  + .1 results in 0.30000000000000004
 .7  + .1 results in 0.7999999999999999
1.1  + .1 results in 1.2000000000000002
```

and so on...

Can anyone explain (in detail) why? Probably some binary rounding stuff. But I like to really know what happens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, because `.2` isn't actually .2; it's actually the closest representable double-precision number, which is

```
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125.
```

Similarly, `.1` is really

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

When you add those together, the result is rounded again to the nearest representable number, which is

```
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

Finally, when you print it out, that number gets rounded to 17 decimal digits, giving the result you observe.

Your other examples follow the same pattern.