# How to type hint prices?

Tags: php, currency, floating-point-conversion

How to type hint prices in PHP?

My example function:

```
function dividePrice(float $a, float $b) : float
{
    return $a / $b;
}

echo dividePrice(132.32, 23.24);
```

This return: 5.6936316695353

Is it safe and well calculated if I use float for type hinting? If not float how to do it?

Comment: What kind of prices? Some currencies don't have decimal points, or even fractional amounts. If only USD, then a price is a float anyway you look at it, and you just have to force round to string or restricted decimal length (if storing in db).

Comment: Only USD. In DB should be as decimal, but in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers have inherent rounding issues, as a lot of decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating point, and are only [close approximations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318283/floating-point-0-2-0-1-rounding-error).

---

To represent money in PHP, I can only advise to use a proper money library that performs exact calculations, and handles rounding explicitly.

Example with [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money), a library I authored:

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$money = Money::of('132.32', 'USD');
echo $money->dividedBy('23.24', RoundingMode::HALF_UP); // USD 5.69
```

---

This library is based on [brick/math](https://github.com/brick/math), a library that performs exact calculations on numbers of any size. You can also use the `brick/math` library directly to pass exact decimal numbers around in your code:

```php
use Brick\Math\BigDecimal;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;

$a = BigDecimal::of('132.32');
$b = BigDecimal::of('23.24');

// Dividing to 2 decimals
echo $a->dividedBy($b, 2, RoundingMode::HALF_UP); // 5.69

// Dividing to 20 decimals
echo $a->dividedBy($b, 20, RoundingMode::HALF_UP); // 5.69363166953528399312
```

---

To reiterate, floats are designed to perform *approximate* calculations. Don't use them for money handling.

An alternative would be to use `int` to represent money, in cents (you still have to be careful with division, though). But I can only encourage you to use a well-established library to make your code more readable and less prone to errors.